UAE Rejected visa without any reason, what are my options?
I am travelling to Pakistan via Abu Dhabi. I applied for a transit visa for 48 hours as I will be there for a 17 hour overlay (so thought to roam in the city). The visa got rejected with no information given or what I missed, etc...?
I emailed their customer service email, but no reply. What are my options? I am in the UK.

What is your citizenship? Where are you travelling from? Do you have any visas or residence permits from other countries? How did you apply? Do you have any adverse visa/immigration history? What airline(s) are you flying with?

What options are you looking for? Can you transit via somewhere else?

@jcaron I thought I tagged as being Pakistani, but it isn't there. I am pakistani but my kids are british national and wife EEA national. I am flying with Etihad, I got flights via trip.com so I think they cannot apply on their behalf, I don't have any adverse history, never been rejected. My niece called them as she is UAE, they said they can not tell reason but I can re-apply.

did you get something figured out? It happened with me as well. I need your guidance.

@Haris when you arrive in Abu Dhabi ask for immigration desk to there and person will assist you and tell you what is missing in your application
